# How to update robot_radius and footprint dynamically for motion planning

Tags: navigation, ros2, mapping, ros-humble, nav2

Hi everyone I am new to using ROS2. So I have a project in which my robot car has to attach a big box to it and then bring it to a certain location. But after attaching the box the robot car while navigating to different location experiences collision on its way. So is there any way were i could write code in python in such a way that nav2 automatically take into account when the box is attached to the robot and when not and plan accordingly.

Below is link to my yaml file that contains nav2 parameters
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j5dCojO1PWUotAiM51qtvFnsxDkIA2Oo/view?usp=sharing

Ok so after searching i found something related to this
https://answers.ros.org/question/415081/what-is-the-correct-way-to-change-dynamic-footprint/

but the answer at the end is written for ros not for ros2 can somebody pls help me with this.

Ok so after doing ros2 topic list i found these two ros2 topics

1. /local_costmap/published_footprint
2. /global_costmap/published_footprint

So will these be used here and if so do i have to update both of them or just one of them

My second question related to this project is that how do we update the local and global costmaps after i have changed the position of the rack after attaching and detaching from the robo car as it should reflect in the rviz2 .

thank u so much for u patience and help in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the footprint topics from Nav2 can take in a new footprint dynamically!

Your application code (or behavior tree) can publish the updated footprint including the box and that will be used by the costmaps and the planning/control algorithms as long as you have full footprint checking functionalities enabled (i.e. DWB/MPPI using footprint-considering settings). This is a fully supported and intention feature for reasons like what you mention.

Comment: Sorry to bother u but can explain in detail how to achieve this. i am using AMCl planner with DWB. Do we have to susbcribe to any specific topic or call any specfic service that automatically changes the robot footprint dynamically?